# two textview with wrap content mask each other when text become longer

Tags: android, android-layout, textview

I have two TextView in a LinearLayout (horizontal orientation). what I need is that, my first TextView always have width to wrap it's content in a single line, and the second TextView which is loaded dynamically use rest of space to show it's content and it doesn't matter if it become multiple line.

when I use code below, when the content is less it shows perfect but when the content of second TextView become longer, it mask first TextView :-(

```
<LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="right"
                android:gravity="right"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/itemdescription"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="right"
                    android:gravity="right"
                    android:padding="5dp"
                    android:textSize="18sp" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="right|center_vertical"
                    android:gravity="right|center_vertical"
                    android:padding="5dp"
                    android:text="توضیحات:"
                    android:textSize="18sp" />

            </LinearLayout>
```

can you help me to solve my problem?
thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make use of weights. Give each text view equal weight and give a small margin between them:

```
<LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="right"
                android:weightSum="2"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/itemdescription"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:padding="5dp"
                    android:textSize="18sp" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:padding="5dp"
                    android:text="توضیحات:"
                    android:textSize="18sp" />

            </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to set a maximal width to your second textview. You can do this in your xml file. Simply add: 
android:maxWidth="100dp"

Answer (score 0):

Try using weight attribute like this:

```html
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="right" >

        <TextView
           android:id="@+id/itemdescription"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_weight="0"
            android:text=":FIELD" />
    </LinearLayout>
```